# Compare CSV entries with JSON files using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, csv

I have a CSV file called `refrigerator.csv` like so:

```
+---------------+---------+--------+------------+
| item          |  amount |  unit  |  use by    |
+---------------+---------+--------+------------+
| bread         | 10      | slices | 25/12/2017 |
+---------------+---------+--------+------------+
| cheese        | 10      | slices | 25/12/2017 |
+---------------+---------+--------+------------+
| butter        | 250     | grams  | 25/12/2017 |
+---------------+---------+--------+------------+
| peanut butter | 250     | grams  | 2/12/2017  |
+---------------+---------+--------+------------+
| mixed salad   | 500     | grams  | 26/12/2016 |
+---------------+---------+--------+------------+
```

and a JSON file called `recipes.json` like so:

```
[
  {
    "name": "grilledcheeseontoast",
    "ingredients": [
      {
        "item": "bread",
        "amount": "2",
        "unit": "slices"
      },
      {
        "item": "cheese",
        "amount": "2",
        "unit": "slices"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "saladsandwich",
    "ingredients": [
      {
        "item": "bread",
        "amount": "2",
        "unit": "slices"
      },
      {
        "item": "mixedsalad",
        "amount": "200",
        "unit": "grams"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "peanutbuttersandwich",
    "ingredients": [
      {
        "item": "bread",
        "amount": "2",
        "unit": "slices"
      },
      {
        "item": "peanut butter",
        "amount": "250",
        "unit": "grams"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have been tasked to create a console app using php to take these two files in a line arguments and output the recommended recipes as per items in fridge. Ingredients that have passed their useby date cannot be used. Any directions on how I can go about doing this? (I'm a PHP beginner)

Comment: are you using composer?

Comment: I don't know what composer is, i'm using XAMPP environment if that's what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter out everything from the CSV file with an expired date (e.g. the current date is great than the date listed in the CSV file). PHP has builtin support for reading and writing CSV files. `str_getcsv()` is one of them. The documentation can be found: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php . You can use this function to read the file one by one and turn it into an array. The comments provide some useful pointers as well.

After the filtering, read the JSON file with the builtin file read functions, e.g. `file_get_contents()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). This will read the given file, pointed by the filename argument, into a string. Use the builtin `json_decode()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to transform the input string to either an object or an associative array.

After transforming the JSON file into an object or array, you can loop over your filtered ingredients list and check if there is any match in your recipes data. You can go for the straight forward method by looping over your recipes data over and over again, until you find a match, or try to use and/or combine more builtin functions to solve the problem.

Try to break your solution into smaller problems, and focus on solving these problems.

Comment: Hi Thanks for you're response, as per your suggestion I've developed the following code `https://justpaste.it/1b57n`. I'm having difficulty creating the loops to do the matching between the array obtained from the csv file and from the json file, any directions on how I can go about creating the loops. Hopefully, I'm going in the right direction so far.